# What is best way to declaration a variable ? follow below example?

Tags: java

Example:

```
String one="One", two="Two", Three="Three";
```

(or)

```
String one="One";
String two="Two";
String Three="Three";
```

See, above e.g which one is best way in real time? what is difference both us? i am using 1st one it is save the class file memory. but all programmer use 2nd one.why there was use 2nd i did not understand?tell me any one

Comment: `all programmer use 2nd one.` what does it mean in means. in your project??

Comment: It is good practice to use first one because it is efficient than second one.

Comment: @rishikeshtadaka - What do you mean by efficient? Code size or execution time? Execution time will not be affected.

Comment: They will compile to the exact same byte code, there is no difference. Use whichever is consistent with the rest of the project.

Comment: The question seems to assume Java.  Why is it then also tagged as C/C++?  If you want to know about best practices for variable declaration in these languages, it might be better to split that into a separate question.

Comment: first one is efficient in terms on performance, because compiler parse it faster than second one.

Comment: @rishikeshtadaka that's not right, look at my answer. Or just look at a bytecode

Comment: @rishikeshtadaka the <1ms time you save compiling by parsing #1 is vastly outdone by the readability of #2.

Comment: I'd be more concerned with the uppercase in the variable name `Three` which really makes it harder to read.

Comment: Code size is main in my project bcz i am developed android apps.

Answer (score 8):

Programming is always about maintainability. The code you wrote should be able to be modified by a developer coming in 100 years after you.

Maintainability rely heavily in code readability. Second one is more readable than the first one.

And further more second one is much more flexible. In the sense if you want to change the datatype of `two` in second method it is much easier than first method.

Comment: k k thanks .but we r develop android app so we r maintain size also.final both r working same right?

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference. Compiler will do it in the best way, so in byte code you would have always (in both cases):

```
   // access flags 0x0
   Ljava/lang/String; one

   // access flags 0x0
   Ljava/lang/String; two

   // access flags 0x0
   Ljava/lang/String; Three
```

Going this way, use what is more appriopriate in your project. Don't care about the memory!

Answer (score 3):

Both methodologies are equivalent, although the first one might be less readable under some circumstances. 
What you should **not** do is to declare a variable starting with an upper-case letter, as you do with your 3rd String.